# In Nest 1.7.1 Delete or DeleteByQuery nothing works

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In Nest 1.7.1 Delete or DeleteByQuery nothing works for me.

I am trying to delete below documents:

```
Article article1 = new Article()
            {
                Id = 1111,
                Title = "Title - Test Elastic Search",
                Summary = "Summary - Test Elastic Search",
                Body = "Body - Test Elastic Search",
                ArticleDate = _dateToday,
                Author = new Author() { Id = 100, Name = "Mikey" },
            };

Article article2 = new Article()
            {
                Id = 2222,
                Title = "Title - Test Elastic Search",
                Summary = "Summary - Test Elastic Search",
                Body = "Body - Test Elastic Search",
                ArticleDate = _dateToday,
                Author = new Author() { Id = 100, Name = "Mikey" },
                Published = true
            };
```

I was expecting below queries would delete single document and all documents in an index but no query is deleting.

`_elasticClient.Delete(article).Found;`

```
_elasticClient.DeleteByQuery<Article>(q => q.Query(t => t.Term(m => m.OnField(f => f.Id).Value(articleId))))
                                      .Found;


_elasticClient.DeleteByQuery<Article>(q => q.MatchAll()).IsValid;
```

Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you expect the outcome to be? What is being sent to Elasticsearch and what is Elasticsearch returning? You'll need to provide more detail

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: Can you show what the `Article` type looks like?

Comment: '"_index": "articlestest",
            "_type": "articles",
            "_id": "1111",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "bodyWithoutHtml": "Body - Test Elastic Search",
               "summaryWithoutHtml": "Summary - Test Elastic Search",
               "version": 0,
               "wordCount": 0,
               "body": "Body - Test Elastic Search",
                "lastEditedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
               "author": {
                  "name": "Mikey",
                  "id": 100
               },
               "authorName": "Mikey"'

Comment: I mean the C# type :) Could you add it to your question? The more information you're able to provide, the better the chance of getting a _good_ answer ;)

Comment: Updated the question.Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: I have recently upgraded to 1.7.5 from 0.90.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example

```
void Main()
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"), "articles");
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists("articles").Exists)
    {
        client.DeleteIndex("articles");
    }

    client.CreateIndex("articles", c => c
        .AddMapping<Article>(m => m
            .MapFromAttributes()
        )
    );

    var today = DateTime.Now.Date;

    var article1 = CreateArticle(1111, today);
    var article2 = CreateArticle(2222, today);
    var article3 = CreateArticle(3333, today);
    var article4 = CreateArticle(4444, today);

    var bulkRequest = new BulkDescriptor();
    bulkRequest.Index<Article>(i => i.Document(article1));
    bulkRequest.Index<Article>(i => i.Document(article2));
    bulkRequest.Index<Article>(i => i.Document(article3));
    bulkRequest.Index<Article>(i => i.Document(article4));
    bulkRequest.Refresh();

    client.Bulk(bulkRequest);

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Article>(q => q.MatchAll());

    Console.WriteLine("Documents from search: {0}. Expect 4", searchResponse.Documents.Count());

    client.Delete(article1, d => d.Refresh());

    searchResponse = client.Search<Article>(q => q.MatchAll());
    Console.WriteLine("Documents from search {0}. Expect 3", searchResponse.Documents.Count());

    client.Delete(article2, d => d.Refresh());

    searchResponse = client.Search<Article>(q => q.MatchAll());
    Console.WriteLine("Documents from search {0}. Expect 2", searchResponse.Documents.Count());

    client.DeleteByQuery<Article>(q => q.MatchAll());

    searchResponse = client.Search<Article>(q => q.MatchAll());
    Console.WriteLine("Documents from search {0}. Expect 0", searchResponse.Documents.Count());

}

private Article CreateArticle(int id, DateTime articleDate)
{
    return  new Article()
    {
        Id = id,
        Title = "Title - Test Elastic Search",
        Summary = "Summary - Test Elastic Search",
        Body = "Body - Test Elastic Search",
        ArticleDate = articleDate,
        Author = new Author() { Id = 100, Name = "Mikey" },
        Published = true
    };
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Title{ get; set;}
    public string Summary { get; set;}
    public string Body { get; set;}
    public DateTime ArticleDate { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

results in

```
Documents from search: 4. Expect 4
Documents from search 3. Expect 3
Documents from search 2. Expect 2
Documents from search 0. Expect 0
```

as expected.

Something to bear in mind is that Elasticsearch is *eventually consistent* meaning that a document that is indexed does not appear in *search* results until after a **[refresh interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/index-modules.html)** (by default, 1 second); Likewise, with a delete query, a document marked for deletion will appear in search results until the refresh interval has elapsed.

A GET request on a given document with a given id **will** however return the document before the refresh interval.

If you need documents to be searchable (or to not show in search results after deletion), you can refresh the index after an operation as I did with the bulk and delete calls above, using `.Refresh()`. You might be tempted to call refresh after *every* operation, however I would recommend using it only when you really need to as it adds overhead to the cluster and called *all* the time would likely degrade performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot,after using 'BulkDescriptor' it worked fine.But what is the difference between '_elasticClient.Index' and 'var bulkRequest = new BulkDescriptor();
   bulkRequest.Index<Article>(i => i.Document(articleToIndex));'

Comment: `Index()` indexes a single document, with `Bulk()`, you can perform multiple operations in one round trip. In this example, indexing many documents

Comment: Hi @Russ, yesterday without checking properly i said its working. I replaced my code with `var bulkRequest = new BulkDescriptor();
   bulkRequest.Index<Article>(i => i.Document(article1));
   bulkRequest.Index<Article>(i => i.Document(article2));

   bulkRequest.Refresh();
   _elasticClient.Bulk(bulkRequest);`

Comment: I have just observed that above code is not at all indexing my articles :( Can you please help me?

Comment: This `_elasticClient.IndexMany(articlesToIndex, _indexName, DocumentType);` indexes my documents but when i try to delete documents with `_elasticClient.DeleteByQuery<Article>(q => q.MatchAll())` --they are not deleted.

Comment: Are you sure `_elasticClient.DeleteByQuery<Article>(q => q.MatchAll()).IsValid` is `true`?

Comment: Yes ,it's coming as true.

Comment: `IndexMany()` is just a convenience wrapper for `Bulk()` so if that works, there's something wrong with your bulk call if it is not working. You should run a web debugging proxy like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what is being sent and returned from Elasticsearch. the code above works with NEST 1.7.1 against Elasticsearch 1.7.5. **NOTE : if you're running against Elasticsearch 2.x, you need to use a NEST 2.x client and will need to install the DeleteByQuery Plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html)**

Comment: Did you run fiddler and look at the requests and responses?

Comment: Yeah,i did debug and documents are indexed with `IndexMany()`.When i tried deleting manually from fiddler DELETE `http://localhost:9200//articlestest/articles/` then the documents got deleted and response is `{"acknowledged":true}`

Comment: And when you send via NEST? What do you see in Fiddler?

Comment: I am sorry, delete query actually works in plugin now.Previously ,i have included `_search` in the delete query that's the reason documents were not deleted.I am still puzzled why this `_elasticClient.DeleteByQuery<Article>(q => q.MatchAll())` is not deleting the documents

Comment: Somehow fiddler is not capturing the Nest delete request :(

Comment: If you're running against localhost, you need to set the host to `ipv4.fiddler` so that fiddler can proxy requests - http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Observe-Traffic/Troubleshooting/NoTrafficToLocalhost. **Which version of Elasticsearch are you running against?**

Comment: In Fiddler,i am filtering `localhost;` (I was thinking this way it will capture my localhost requests).I am using 1.7.5

Comment: After  pointing to `http://ipv4.fiddler:9200` instead of `localhost`,i can now see fiddler capturing all requests( this is brilliant :D ).So the Delete query response says successful.Response looks like this : `{"_indices":{"articlestest":{"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0}}}}` But it is not deleting the documents at all - i am saying this because i can see the documents when i make a `GET` request.

Comment: Are you making the GET request after the `refresh_interval` time? If you think it's a bug in Elasticsearch, the best thing to do is open an issue at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues. It's worth looking at the elasticsearch logs too

Comment: yes, i making GET request after `_elasticClient.Refresh(f => f.Indices(_testIndexName));`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working finally.

The delete request which is sent via `NEST` in fiddler is `DELETE /articlestest/article/_query` and the query which worked in plugin is this `DELETE /articlestest/articles/_query` ( the document type name was misspelled in the code).That's the reason ,query was not deleting the documents via `NEST`.And the bad thing is ,it doesn't even complain about the non-existent document type :( It took me a while to found that issue.